# Swift 2 Call Function in CompletionHandler

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, nsurlsession

I am new in Swift. I am unable to call a function as soon as I download JSON data from server using `NSURLSession`. Here is my code -

```
func loadTableViewWithServerData(_url:String){
        showOverLayView()
        let postEndpoint: String = _url
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let url = NSURL(string: postEndpoint)!
        session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {
            (data, response, error) in

            guard let responseData = data else {
                print("Error: did not receive data")
                return
            }
            let post: NSMutableArray
            do {
                post = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData,
                    options: []) as! NSMutableArray
                self.dataArray = SHDataAccess().arrayFromPlist(post)

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                     self.questionTableView.reloadData()

                     //hideOverLayView() /* it shows error here*/

                 })


            } catch  {
                print("error trying to convert data to JSON")
            }

        }).resume()
    }
```

When I try to call `hideOverLayView() /* it shows error here*/` it shows the error:

> Error : Call to method 'hideOverLayView()' in closure requires explicit 'self' to make capture semantics explicit.

How do I fix this? Or what is the right way to call another function where i refresh my view when server data is available.

Here is my `hideOverLayView() /* it shows error here*/` function -

```
func hideOverLayView(){
        self.overLayView.imageProgress.stopAnimating()
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
            self.overLayView.hidden = true
        })
    }
```

Comment: Does the `hideOverLayView` function exist in your class?  Can you call `self.hideOverLayView()`?

Comment: So does `self.hideOverLayView()` work?  What is the full error you are getting?

Comment: Also, what is the error? That will point to the problem.

Comment: Error : Call to method 'hideOverLayView()' in closure requires explicit 'self' to make capture semantics explicit.
I tried with using Self.hideOverLayView() it shows error as well

Comment: That's odd, did you try with a lowercase s in `self`?  Explicitly implying self by calling `self.hideOverLayView()` should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're in a closure, you need to explicitly call class methods with `self`.  Without `self`, the context of your method is ambiguous.

Change `hideOverLayView()` to `self.hideOverLayView()` inside your `dispatch_async` block.

Comment: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    self.dataReceievedFromServer()
                })

thats way I call it. By the way, i change methodName. but seems still error

Comment: @Shohrab: no it's not how you are calling it. Please add the `self.` as indicated in this answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could try `self?.hideOverLayView()` to avoid the warning.
One more thing you could do is adding `[weak self]` at the beginning of the closure to make self weak.